# UITextField and UITableView on a single view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to make a view controller that has one text field that populates the tableview below, ideally the user will be able to continue to add to the tableview without jumping between two views.

I previously had it working with the text field on one view that populates a UITableView and used prepareForSegue to push the data to the table, but I haven't been able to get it to work with just one view.

Can anyone please point out where I'm going wrong or push me to a tutorial / documentation to help?

Edit: Clarity

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var items: [String] = ["Pls", "work", "pls", "work", "pls"]
var foodGroup: FoodGroup = FoodGroup(itemName:"")

//var foodGroup: [FoodGroup] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Selected cell #\(indexPath)")
}

func addFood(sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (countElements(self.textField.text) > 0) {
        self.foodGroup = FoodGroup(itemName: self.textField.text)
    }
}

@IBAction func addFoodToList() {
    let source = FoodGroup
    let foodGroup:FoodGroup = source.foodGroup

    if foodGroup.itemName != "" {
        self.foodGroup.append(foodGroup)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Don't you just have a main view with two subviews?  What is the need for segue?

Comment: Perhaps my comment wasn't clear. I had the data being parsed between two views and it worked. I'm now trying to integrate the textfield and tableview into one controller and the method I used to parse the data from one view to another no longer works. I'm stuck trying to find the method to parse the value from text field to table view.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "parse the data from one from one view to another".  You parse the data as necessary, then assign it as you need to.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Well, presuming you want to add a new row each time something's entered in the text view, you'd parse the data when the user clicks done or whatever (I don't know what the delegate method is in Swift), then add that info as a new entry to the dataSource object for the table view.  Then do `reloadData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your intention here is to have your dataSource be an array of FoodGroup objects.  If this is indeed the case you can get rid of your foodGroup instance variable and update your items definition to be like so:

```
var items = [FoodGroup]()
```

then in addFoodToList:

```
if self.textField.text != "" {
    let foodGroup = FoodGroup(itemName: self.textField.text)
    self.items.append(foodGroup)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and finally in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

let foodGroup = self.items[indexPath.row] as FoodGroup
cell.textLabel.text = foodGroup.itemName

return cell
```

Also I don't quite see the intention of your the addFood(sender: AnyObject!) function. Looks like cruft. I would get rid of it.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for a push in the right direction. It's building now but when addFoodToList is called the app crashes because it's receiving NIL. Is it something in the let source that's breaking it?